# What does the dollar sign mean inside an attribute selector in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, dollar-sign

There is this jQuery which seems to look for all elements with `id="scuba"`, but then it uses attr() to pull the id out? Could "scuba" be part of the id and attr pulls the entire id out? I've never seen the $ inside an attribute selector, just outside like the example below.

```
$('*[id$=scuba]').attr('id')
```

So my questions are:

1. What does the `$` or `$=` do in this example
2. What does this code do?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Comment: First stop for such questions: The documentation. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**The dollar sign**

The first `$` is a shorthand for the `jQuery()` function, the [jQuery object constructor](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

In other words, it's a variable called `$` that's been assigned a function called `jQuery`, as can been seen in the unminified version of the jQuery source: `window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;`

**The dollar-equals sign**

The second `$` is part of a jQuery selector called [Attribute Ends With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) . When used in an attribute selector, `$=` is a logical operator that literally means "*true if the left-hand value ends with the right-hand value*".

**What this script actually does**

Overall, this snippet first selects any element with an `id` attribute ending in `scuba`. It then retrieves the `id` value of the first element from the resulting jQuery object.

Comment: Sorry about the simple question, I didn't know what the term was called and didn't realize that those sorts of selectors existed. Thank you!

Comment: @BradleyOesch IMHO, I don't think it's "simple". If you don't know what to search, it's not that "simple" to get results. Not to mention that in the case of `$` that's even more difficult.

Comment: This is now the first Google result for `jquery dollar equals`, so I'm glad someone answered :D

Answer (score 2):

This code selects all DOM elements that have `id` attributes that end in `scuba` and returns their `id` values.

I'm pretty sure it's a better idea to include quotes around `scuba`, though.