# How to effectively use $ in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am relatively new to Javascript and Jquery. I've been looking through some code for a potential project and I see constant use of '$'. Through the context I can get an idea of what it means, but I don't have enough of a grasp to understand how to manipulate it.

For example, this line seems to take the csv file and returns a string variable called data with the contents of the csv file. But I don't understand how or why it does that.

```
$.get('browserData.csv', function(data)){
```

How do people familiar with Jquery effectively use the '$'?

Comment: What do you mean effectively?

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: `$` is just the name of the jQuery object.  If you're asking "how do I learn jQuery" then I'm afraid that's too broad for a single Stack Overflow question.

Comment: `$` is an alias for the `jQuery` library object (aka. namespace). `$.get` is equivalent to `jQuery.get`

Answer (score 3):

```
$("JustaboutAnything");// As a selector
$.get("afile"); // Rendering Ajax
$(function();// Declaring Document Ready
```

This is question is not specific.

Like @BLGT said, $ is an alias for the jQuery library object (aka. namespace)

http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 2):

> **The dollar sign**
>
> The first $ is a shorthand for the jQuery() function, the jQuery
>   object constructor.
>
> In other words, it's a variable called $ that's been assigned a
>   function called jQuery, as can been seen in the unminified version of
>   the jQuery file: window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950823/what-does-the-dollar-sign-mean-inside-an-attribute-selector-in-jquery)

TL;DR: It's shorter than writing "jQuery" all the time. You use it everytime you want access to jQuery specific functionality.

Comment: So it's like a shortcut for all JQuery library functions only?

Comment: Short answer, yes. Though, there might be sometimes exceptions.